# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Flask Redirect

Tags: python, flask

I can't get Flask to redirect!

I keep getting a

```
File "/Users/kyle.calica-steinhil/Code/wcp2018/wcp18/app/app.py", line 32, in slackRedirect
    return redirect(url)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have no idea why this is not working. I'm passing a string in redirect() I'm pretty sure that's what it takes.

I've also tried `'` to `"`

Code:

```
slackAPI='https://slack.com/oauth/authorize'
slack_client_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
scope='bot'
redirect='http://localhost:5000/'

@app.route('/auth')
def slackRedirect():
    url = slackAPI+'?client_id='+slack_client_id+'&scope='+scope+'&redirect_uri='+redirect
    return redirect(url)
```

Comment: What do you think this line does? `redirect='http://localhost:5000/'`

Comment: In other words, you're trampling over the Flask `redirect` method by choosing to call one of your strings `redirect`

Comment: actually i forgot a return statement *facepalm*, the variable expression actually still works but I still changed it to `redirect_uri`

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining what [redirect](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.redirect) means. `redirect` redirects client to target location, so just rename `redirect` to something else, following line:

```
redirect_url='http://localhost:5000/'
```

Comment: Instead of removing, he'll have to rename it to something else since he is using this variable for redirection later.

Comment: actually i forgot a return statement *facepalm*, the variable expression actually still works but I still changed it to `redirect_uri`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is with naming conflicts. Your module level variable `redirect` actually overrides the `flask.redirect()` method that you are trying to use:

```
redirect='http://localhost:5000/'
```

Rename this `redirect` variable to something else and your problem will be solved. That's assuming you've properly imported the `flask.redirect` method in your module:

```
from flask import  redirect
```

Comment: actually i forgot a return statement *facepalm*, the variable expression actually still works but I still changed it to `redirect_uri`